# SuperWebSocket what is the meaning of KeepAliveTime

Tags: c#, websocket

In SuperWebSocket i use the config property IdleSessionTimeOut to delete sessions that are Idle but what is the meaning of KeepAliveTime?

Answer (score 1):

In networking, `Keep Alive` usually refers to the period of time between "heart beat" messages that the client / server will send to each other to very that the connection is still open and alive.  If the message fails to send the sender knows that the receiver has disconnected.

[Keepalive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) at Wikipedia